# ingress not getting any extra points from portal hacking

Tags: ingress

It seems like I am Stuck with 1130XP points and I don't get any more from hacking portals I have hacked in previous days. Is there a limit on the experience points one can receive from certain geographical areas or is it that hacking is limited in the XP points that can give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these portals changed allegiance? You only get 100 XP from hacking enemy portals, not portals that belong to your faction.

Comment: This was exactly the case. Thx.